# What is this iOS control?

Tags: iphone, ios

I can't seem to find any reference to this user control (IP address combo box) in the documentation. Is it private, or is there an open-source alternative?

[image: iOS user control]

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a UITableView with 3 sections.  The first section contains one row with a UIButton within a UITableViewCell.  The second section contains one row with a UiSegmentedControl within a UITableViewCell.  The third section is composed of just standard UITableViewCells.

Read up in the UITableView delegate and data source protocols to understand how to implement.

Good luck

T

Comment: Thanks. Not sure why I couldn't find a reference to it...

Answer (score 4):

That's a UISegmentedControl.  From the documentation 'Displays multiple segments, each of which functions as a discrete button.'

Answer (score 0):

It is a Segmented Control.  (can drag a segmented control onto your nib, then in the configuration it lets you configure how many segments in the control and the text for each segment).  See doco for the UISegmentedControl class.